# "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0" Error

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

Whenever i add firebase database dependency it shows appcompat error. Like this

> "All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and
>   com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0"

```
   dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
        layout:1.1.3'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
       androidTestImplementation 
       'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
   }
```

Comment: what is gradle targeted version code and name ?

Comment: post your app level and project level gradle because i tried your dependency and its working fine

Comment: also `com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0` also this version 28.0.0

Comment: compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.uemultancampus"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 28

Comment: thanks for response but i giving error here.

Comment: @ShahzadRasool If your Android Studio version is 3.3.2 & your target SDK version is 28, the build tools version should be `buildToolsVersion "28.0.3" `   Add the dependency `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0' ` along with `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' `  Also stable release of Support Library 28.0.0 and is the last feature release under the android.support packaging, and developers are encouraged to migrate to AndroidX.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55585484/4649110)

Answer (score 1):

> "All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0. Examples include
>   com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0 and
>   com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.1.0"

**Solution:** Adding `com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0` dependency into your gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
    layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

    // Add this line
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependency `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'`    along with `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'`

Also stable release of Support Library 28.0.0 and is the last feature release under the android.support packaging, and developers are encouraged to migrate to AndroidX

```
  android {
  compileSdkVersion 28
  buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"


 defaultConfig {
 applicationId "com.your_project_name"
 minSdkVersion 23
 targetSdkVersion 28
 versionCode 1
 multiDexEnabled true
 testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

 dependencies {
 implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
 implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
    layout:1.1.3'
 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
 androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
 implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5' 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'

implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

add to dependencies and change

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.2'
```

This is working for me