# Firebase version conflicts with support library

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I know this is a common question and I already read several posts and modify many times my gradle file but I can't find the solution.

> The error message is: All com.android.support libraries must use the
>   exact same version specification. Found versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0.

But I don't know where the 26.1.0 version is. Any idea how to fix it?

This is my **build.gradle(module:app)**

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
  apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

  android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.emojify_kotlin"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
  }

  dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
 }

 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And this my **project gradle file**

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using gradle `app:dependencies`, get a list of dependencies:

```
 +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:..
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:..
|         \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:...
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16....
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16...
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:15....
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0
|    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0 ->.......
```

it shows firebase needed `com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0`, so you have to overwritten it
with **`com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0`**

Comment: that's work perfect!! where did you find that information??

Comment: @Coeus I got the same type of error in my application

Comment: but where did you find the list of dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
dependencies{
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.8'
}
```

dependency in your app gradle from

```
dependencies{
   implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.0'
}
```

and then sync your project with these changes.

Comment: same problem :/

Answer (score 0):

override your firebase dependency with

```
  com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: humm which old version?

Comment: override your firebase dependency with    com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0