# Android studio(gradle) versions compatibility

Tags: java, android, firebase, androidx

I have this issue. Android studio(Gradle) versions compatibility issue. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue. All the versions of dependencies that I have used are mentioned below. I think this is a version problem. Tried much. But couldn't solve. Can you please help me. What can i do to solve this problem.

Project Level Gradle file:

```
allprojects {
    ext {
        appName = "FbaseDemo"
        majorVersion = "0"
        minorVersion = "1"
        patchVersion = "1"

        supportLibrary = '26.0.0'
        constraintLayout = '2.0.0-beta2'
        virgilSdk = '5.1.2'
        virgilCrypto = "5.0.2@aar"
        rxJava = "2.1.5"
        rxAndroid = "2.0.2"
        retrofit = "2.3.0"
        gson = "2.8.0"
        butterKnife = '10.1.0'
        networkTracker = '3.0.3'
        dagger = '2.24'
        loggingInterceptor = '4.0.1'
        rxRetrofitAdapter = '2.6.0'
        converterGson = "2.3.0"
        apacheCommons = "3.7"
        firebaseCore = '17.0.1'
        firebaseAuth = '18.1.0'
        firebaseFirestore = "17.0.1"
        room = '1.1.1'
//        crashlytics = "2.9.3"
    }


apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.virgilsecurity.virgilonfire"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName majorVersion + "." + minorVersion + "." + patchVersion
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", appName + "-v" + versionName)
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Project Level Dependencies:

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Support

    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:$constraintLayout"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibrary"

    // RxJava
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxAndroid"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxJava"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:$rxRetrofitAdapter"

    // Retrofit
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.6.1"

    // Gson
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.1"

    // Logging Interceptor
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$loggingInterceptor"

    // ButterKnife
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butterKnife"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$butterKnife"

    // Network Tracker
    implementation "com.github.pwittchen:reactivenetwork-rx2:$networkTracker"

    // Virgil Security
    implementation "com.virgilsecurity.sdk:crypto-android:$virgilCrypto"
    implementation "com.virgilsecurity.sdk:sdk:$virgilSdk"

    // Dagger
    implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$dagger"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger"
    annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$dagger"

    // Apache commons
    implementation "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.9"

    // Firebase
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$firebaseCore"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:$firebaseAuth"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:20.2.0"
//    implementation "com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:$crashlytics"

    // Room
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$room"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$room"
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$room"
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.0.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

App level Gradle file:

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'

        // Crashlytics
//        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
    }
}





android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.virgilsecurity.virgilonfire"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName majorVersion + "." + minorVersion + "." + patchVersion
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", appName + "-v" + versionName)
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}



dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0"
    implementation "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:$constraintLayout"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibrary"
```

**Android resource linking failed with the next error:**

```
C:\Users\isufernando\Desktop\New folder\demo-firebase-android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2476: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
C:\Users\isufernando\Desktop\New folder\demo-firebase-android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2476: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.
```

Comment: please mention logcats

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you edit your question to include the error you're getting?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin, he putted the error in the same box with the code (at the bottom)

Comment: @F.Lazarescu Thanks for pointing it out. it takes a while to find, and should be clearly marked - for example in another box, or right in the start. As it stands, I hope you agree it's not really clearly posted.

Comment: Error is in the middle

Comment: Android resource linking failed
C:\Users\isufernando\Desktop\New folder\demo-firebase-android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2476: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
C:\Users\isufernando\Desktop\New folder\demo-firebase-android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2476: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Comment: you are using the latest version of `firebase` it depends on the latest version of support lib, so update support lib version

Comment: How can I do it

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55585208/firebase-version-conflicts-with-support-library/55585484

Comment: This support library should not use a different version (26) than the compileSdkVersion (28)

What can I do for it

Answer (score 1):

> resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
>   resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

Change the `compileSdkVersion` to:

```
compileSdkVersion 28
```

[`fontVariationSettings`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#fontVariationSettings) and [`ttcIndex`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#ttcIndex) were added in api **level 28**.

Also you are using

```
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0"
```

Firebase migrated to AndroidX in the latest release. 
It means that you are using both, support libraries and androidx libraries.

You can:

- migrate to androidx as described below
- downgrade your firebase dependencies (but it is not a real solution because you have to migrate before or after)

You can check the [official release notes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#ttcIndex):

> **Warning:** This release is a **MAJOR** version update and breaking change.
>   The latest update to Google Play services and Firebase includes the following changes:

Migration from Android Support Libraries to Jetpack (AndroidX) Libraries. Libraries will not work unless you make the following changes in your app:

- Upgrade `com.android.tools.build:gradle` to v3.2.1 or later.
- **Upgrade `compileSdkVersion` to 28 or later.**
- Update your app **to use Jetpack (AndroidX)**; follow the instructions in [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#fontVariationSettings).

Comment: Again another error was occurred .
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: @user11864882 Post the new error pls. I think it could be related to androidx and support libraries